# Spacing out factors in products

Tags: math-mode, spacing, microtype

In a document like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
$f f_g h^{i_jk^l} m$
\end{document
```

is it possible to increase the spacing in top level products locally/globally? The desired output should resemble `$f \, f_g \, h^{i_jk^l} \, m$`, but probably with an adjustable width, probably smaller than an actual `\,`.

Comment: TeX puts no space between ordinary symbols. If you want to space them out, you have to do it manually. Why would you?

Comment: @egreg In the document in question, many symbols carry sub- and superscripts. In my impression, with more spacing, it becomes more readable. I have hoped that there is some possibility to insert some spacing using microtype or the like.

Comment: you need to do it manually, although you can have less than `\,` if you use `\mskip` (or amsmath `\mspace`) `\,` is `\thinmuskip` which is normally 3mu, so you can use 1 or 2 mu if you prefer, or choose a different font with wider side bearings

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it, at least, possible to write a macro `\spacedoutproduct{...}` that inserts an `\mspace` or whatsoever between any two factors? But probably I am faster with a Regex replacement in my tex file than with writing a macro…

Comment: it's possible in simple cases but very fragile and likely to break things. I would not do it I would add `\,` or similar command at teh points that I wanted to add space.

Comment: but if your issue is just subscripts try `\setlength\scriptspace{1pt}` then you will get an extra half point after sub/super scripts (the default is .5pt)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that suffices for me; there are only a few other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is just the space after sub/super-scripts try

```
\setlength\scriptspace{1pt}
```

then you will get an extra half point after sub/super-scripts (the default is .5pt)